# Removing photos and songs from iPad storage after sync turned off

Tags: ipad, icloud, photos, storage, mp3

After turning off iCloud sync for Music and Photos, how do I remove the songs and photos that are already there?

I'm setting up an iPad which has a very small amount of storage.

I had hoped that iCloud services would intelligently use the space so I could prioritize apps, and only use storage for photos and songs when it was available.

However it quickly loaded 7.4 gigs of songs and 4 gigs of images.  When I wanted to install more apps, it refused.

So I turned off sync for my music library and my photo library.  I thought this would remove the songs and photos.

I've restarted the iPad and searched the interfaces.  Is there any way to remove these songs and images?

Note, if I need to reset the iPad and restore from a backup, that's ok.  I'm wondering if the backup I make now will preserve the settings I have now, which would imply that no photos or songs should be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Warning : Once you have deleted photos or musics, there is no way back except if you save a backup before doing this (which I advise you to do).

#### For Photos

To delete every single photo on your iPad, go to Photos app. Then, at the of your screen, click on Select [image]. Now, click on the last photo taken, at the very bottom of the recents library, then, tap-and-hold while swiping to the top of your screen on the 2nd most recent photo (the most recent being already selected). And do not let your finger until you have reached the top (so that every photo is selected). Verify at the bottom of your screen that it shows "[number of photos] Photos selected". Then, next to that, click on the bin [image] icon, it will ask you for a confirmation : "Delete [number of photos] items", click on it to accept. Then, go to the Recently Deleted tab in Photos and click on Select [image]. Now, at the bottom of your screen, click on Delete All [image].

[image] [image] [image]

<sub>(Click images to open full size)</sub>

#### For Music

Go to Settings > General > iPhone Storage. Then, in the list, find Music, click on it. Now, click on "Edit" and click on the - sign [image] next to "All Songs".